# I don't have a /dev/dsa yet I have audio!

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I was hacking around and hoping to direct some random data using pipes at /dev/dsa as follows

```
  cat random.file > /dev/dsa
```

...to get some random noise, but I can't manage to find an audio device. I have looked all around the dev folder, there is nothing called /dev/mixer or /dev/audio. I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on an Eeepc 1001p.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might well be using alsa--If there is a `/dev/snd` directory, then that likely the case. Also, according to the  [Alsa-mini Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Alsa-sound-6.html), the results of running `cat /proc/asound/cards` should contain information on your soundcard.

Comment: I am of course assuming, that you mean that regular sound producing applications (eg: VLC, xmms, mplayer) produce sound okay.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that is the device. Thank you. You wouldn't believe how much googling I did before I came here for such a simple question!

Comment: Note: this must be a fairly common problem since the latest Linux kernels (2.6+) has migrated to supporting ALSA, in place of OSS. /dev/dsa is OSS and /dev/snd is ALSA

Comment: I assume that you mean `/dev/dsp` rather than `/dev/dsa`. Funnily enough I didn't spot it the first time round either. :)